# Getting Parse Tree of a Regex in Go

Tags: regex, go, tokenize

I tried using the [`regex.syntax` module](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/) to access the individual tokens of a parsed regular expression without success: the only thing I'm able to output is a simplified/optimized version of the regex.

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp/syntax"
)

func main() {
    p, e := syntax.Parse(`[0120-2]@[ab][0-9]`, 'i')

    fmt.Println(p)
    fmt.Println(e)
}
```

Output:

```
[0-2](?i:@)[A-Ba-b][0-9]
<nil>
```

Can someone give me a simple example of how to traverse and output its parse tree?

Comment: Please post an example of the code you've tried. Otherwise, it sounds like you're looking for the `Parse` function "Parse parses a regular expression string s, controlled by the specified Flags, and returns a regular expression parse tree." http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/#Parse

Comment: @Intermernet: Yeah, I was on mobile, sorry for not posting that right from the start. I think I need the `Parse` function as well but I'm not sure why it's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Parse` function you're calling is right. When you call `fmt.Println(p)`, the parse tree is being converted to a string, which is why the output you're seeing is just an equivalent regexp.

The return value of `Parse` is a pointer to a `syntax.Regexp` struct. To traverse the returned parse tree you want to look at the `Sub` field of the returned struct which lists all the subexpressions (a slice of pointers to `syntax.Regexp` structs). For example:

```
func printSummary(r *syntax.Regexp) {
    fmt.Printf("%v has %d sub expressions\n", r, len(r.Sub))
    for i, s := range r.Sub {
        fmt.Printf("Child %d:\n", i)
        printSummary(s)
    }
}
```

See the [syntax package reference](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/#Regexp) for more fields worth inspecting: `Op` and `Rune` are major ones.

Comment: Totally off-topic, but you do think it would be easier to achieve what I am asking in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815278/porting-invregex-py-to-javascript-node-js) in Go? AFAIK, it doesn't have support for generators (at least not the usual kind).

Comment: You can get something similar to generator using channels: http://play.golang.org/p/0JXsGZf2Kl implements very simple cartesian product for string iterables.